# Is it normal to create RESTful based web simple online store?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, design-patterns, architecture

I design a simple online store. It has a product card, a list of products, the ability to add comments to the product, user registration, search products by price and other criteria. Maybe online store will have mobile clients (android and ios).

I want to try to work with RESTful. Is it normal to create this store, using RESTful? If it is normal, then I have a few questions.

When I create the usual sites, I write the following code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var products = this.productRepository.GetAll();
   return View(products);
}
```

How to change the architecture of the site, if I use RESTful. What must this method sent to client? Html only? And then the client has to execute AJAX request to the api to get the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESTful web services is an HTTP-based services, any HTTP related applications can implement it by using WebApi,WCF, etc.
To build the online store project, of course you can use WebApi to build RESTful web services.
It's hard to say if using RESTful web services is normal or not, you can build an web application without building RESTful web services.
It only depends on your needs and preferences.

Let's say you're using WebApi to build RESTful web services for your project. 
below is an example showing how you can implement it.

**WebApi Controller**

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts() 
    {
        return this.productRepository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

**MVC Action**

Example 1:  Calling Web API controller actions from MVC action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    var webApi = new ProductsController();
    return View(webApi.GetAllProducts());
}
```

Example 2: Populate all products in the view by calling Web API using Ajax

**View:**

```
<div id="contents"></div>
```

**JS file**

```
$(function() {
   showAllProducts();   
   function showAllProducts() {
        var url = "http://localhost:13131/api/Products/";
        $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
            $("#contents").append(result); // here you need do more than this.
        });
    }
});
```

What way to implement Web API depends on your need, there are a lot of way to implement it.
For your project, it's good to try different methods, you can learn more about it in the process.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I want to try to use Angular or Backbone. I think I will try to query the data using Ajax requests.

Comment: hi @Denis, Angular or Backbone are client side implementations. They're very powerful when you're trying to bind data to UI. But they have nothing to do with RESTful web services.